# Not able to pass Timer.sheduledTimer with parameters

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

```
basicPidTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.pidsUsage(indexPid:)), userInfo: pidsIndex, repeats: false)
```

//calling method bellow but not triggering anyhelp?

```
@objc func pidsUsage(indexPid : Int){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter needs to be of type `Timer`. I.e.

```
@objc func pidsUsage(timer : Timer) {

}
```

Comment: k, but how can i pass updated indexPid value ?

Comment: In the timer's `.userInfo` property?

Comment: po sender.userInfo![0] .  getting this while reading userinfo..
error: <EXPR>:3:16: error: type 'Any' has no subscript members
sender.userInfo![0]

Comment: You'd need to cast it. `(timer.userInfo as! [Int])[0]`

Comment: thanks... I do it this way,  let userInfo = sender.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Comment: The more "Swift" way to write that would be `as! [String: AnyObject]`. And `AnyObject` is usually used for converting between Objective-C and Swift, so even better would be to use `[String: Any]`.